# Using LINQ to update every field in SQL row without specifically declaring each field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, asp.net-core

I just wanted to know if there was a way to update every field/property in a SQL row without having to declare an explicit "context.FieldName = model.FieldName" for each field.

What I tried doing was:

1. Pass in the updated model object to the method.
2. Get the DTO object from the db context based on the model object's ID
3. If not null, using AutoMapper, convert the model object in to a DTO object
4. Now set the original DTO object to the newly mapped DTO object
5. Update database (**This is where it fails**)
6. Save Context

But if I explicitly set every single DTO field = to its corresponding model field, it works (obviously). But due to frequent database changes, and the sheer amount of SQL fields, I would like to avoid manually updating every single field and maintaining it every time the database is changed.

Comment: You can just map model object to data transfer object, and then append this object to context, in *modified* state: `dbContext.Entry(dto).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the newest version of automapper,  you can do something like this:

```
public void UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    var customerTopdate=dbContext.Customers.Where(c=>c.Id=customer.Id);
    var result=AutoMapper.Map<Customer>(customer,customerTopdate);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was by far the easiest solution. I updated my AutoMapper and it worked flawlessly. However, the only thing wrong in your code is that  "var result=AutoMapper.Map<Customer>(customer,customerTopdate);" should be "var result=AutoMapper.Map(customer,customerTopdate);".

Comment: @AnthonyMascia To be fair, he's not wrong. He's just explicitly declaring the return type of the Map method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Entity State` for your `entity` for `update` as well as for `delete` and `insert`..

> *Update*

```
dbContext.Entry(yourEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

> *Insert*

```
dbContext.Entry(yourEntity).State = EntityState.Added;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

> *Delete*

```
dbContext.Entry(yourEntity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

And don't forget to call `SaveChanges()` at the end of each operation.

For more information, please visit

> ***<kbd>[Entity states and SaveChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)</kbd>***

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that replied. Here is how I got it to work using the latest version of AutoMapper:

```
public void UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    var customerTopdate=dbContext.Customers.Where(c=>c.Id=customer.Id);

    if (customerTopdate != null {
       _mapper.Map(customer,customerTopdate);
       _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```